# How can I add a second sender address with different SMTP server in iOS?

Tags: ios, email, smtp

I forward my university email address to my GMail account, so I don’t have my university IMAP set up as an account on my iPad (and I don’t want to, because then I’d receive those mails twice). Still, I want to send email using that address, via my university’s SMTP server.

- Is there any way to add another sender address to an account and assign it a different SMTP server than the account’s default SMTP in the iPad’s email client?
- If not, can you recommend another email client for the iPad that has this capability?

Comment: This is still actual in 2018, there's no (obvious) way to bind a sender to a specific SMTP setting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Configuring additional outgoing mail servers](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4519)

from the **Apple support** websites has detail instructions:

1. Go to **Settings → Mail, Contacts, Calendars.**
2. Tap the **Mail account** for which you would like to change the settings.

   If your account is configured to sync Notes or other items, you may need to tap Account Info on the following screen as well.
3. On the Account Info screen, locate the **Outgoing Mail Server** section and tap the existing **SMTP** entry.
4. A list of SMTP servers will appear, with the Primary Server and then Other SMTP Servers. Go to **Other SMTP servers → Add Server...**.

   [image]
5. Enter the additional SMTP server information. Host Name is required.
6. Tap Save.

Comment: Yes, but that page does not explain how to assign the server to an address. It sounds more like “if the default SMTP is down/unreachable, it will try to use the other one instead”. What I want is to always use it for mails I send from one specific address (and always use the default server for the primary address).

Comment: Whenever you compose a new mail, you may choose from which server/address to send it from by tapping on "From:".

Comment: That popup menu only shows addresses for me, not servers.

Comment: @Lukas Each email address is bound to a server in the Mail app.

Comment: And how does that binding work? I can add new email addresses (by entering them comma-separated into the account’s Email field) and new SMTP servers (via the method you described) independently from each other. Also, if I send an email from my university address with the university’s SMTP server set up via that method, it still uses GMail’s SMTP server (according to the mail headers).

Comment: @Lukas If you send mail from a different SMTP server, the receiver of your mail can only see the email address related to this email service. If you just change the name of the address (comma solution), the mail is not sent via a different server. Several mail clients (e.g. Outlook) will be able to see both your email addresses: The one related to the SMTP server and the alias. Apple's mail client only shows the alias - i think. In general it's better to send emails using different servers, not just alias.

Comment: Yes, and I want to send email using a different server – I just don’t see any way to do that without setting up a completely separate email account (the method you linked to above only adds a new SMTP as a backup for the default one and doesn’t allow to specify an email address for use with that server). GMail’s web interface and Sparrow, for example, allow this (using their Send Email As/Alias features and then setting a custom SMTP for an address), but I guess Apple’s client doesn’t.  Anyway, thanks for trying to help, appreciate it. :)

Comment: Resurrecting an old answer, but as of 2023, iOS *still* does not handle selecting the proper SMTP server correctly. If you have multiple aliases configured for a single IMAP account (but with different SMPT servers configured, one for each alias), iOS will *still* only use the primary SMTP server to send the mail, rather than select the SMTP server based on the alias. The difference is subtle in your recipient's inbox—in the former case it will say "from: <alias> via <primary smtp>" as opposed to just "from: <alias>"

Answer (score -1):

Came accross this question and found a way to use a second sender address with a different SMTP server.

1. Configure a second SMTP server for your current mail account as already described [here by gentmatt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44624/how-can-i-add-a-second-sender-address-with-different-smtp-server-in-ios/44626#44626)
2. Go to the primary SMTP server and **un-check the "Server" option**, afterwards it should look like this:

[image: SMTP server configuration]

And now add the email address that should be used for the second SMTP server:

1. Go to **Settings** -> **Mail** -> **Accounts** and select your mail account and tap **Account**
2. Tap the **EMail** field under IMAP ACCOUNT INFORMATION
3. Add your second mail address with **Add Another Email...**

With this configuration, when composing a new mail, per default the primary email address is pre-selected and will use its primary SMTP server.
And when selecting the second sender address in the mail compose form, the secondary mail address with the secondary SMTP will be used.

When replying to a mail, the Mail app automatically picks the mail address the mail was sent to as sender address.

Hopefully this helps.